# Integrating FastPdfKit with a PhoneGap application

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'd like to integrate a FastPdfKit Reader into my PhoneGap application. That is, the PDF reader should be opened within the PhoneGap app, so that the application-related navigation is still visible.

Where do I best start?
Do you know about any publicly available code that gives an example on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you found or generate any solutions for this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is creating a PhoneGap plugin.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins

Here are some tutorials on making plugins for PhoneGap:

http://hiediutley.com/2011/04/15/phonegap-tutorial-series-6-writing-your-own-plugin/

Comment: yep, I'm looking for a PhoneGap plugin. I was hoping to find a PhoneGap FastPdfKit plugin which I can extend instead of wrinting my own from scratch. thanks for your help though.

Comment: Maybe if you can't write the plugin yourself you could find someone in the PhoneGap community interested in writing the plugin. Try the PhoneGap Google Group or #phonegap on free node IRC. It's the kind of thing I would be interested in but I just don't have enough time (unless I needed it for a billable client).